# Nuxt - The environment variables in privateRuntimeConfig exposed in client (in development)?

Tags: nuxt.js

I have a problem.
I use the privateRuntimeConfig in nuxt.config.js... and I see that my environment variable is accessible on the client side (top/localhost:3000/_nuxt/app.js).
 
I have not tested in a production environment.
Why ?

nuxt.config.js

```
env: {
    publicRuntimeConfig: {
      apiUrl: process.env.API_URL
    },
    privateRuntimeConfig: {
      apiUrl: process.env.API_URL
      apiAuthUsername: process.env.API_AUTH_USERNAME,
      apiAuthPassword: process.env.API_AUTH_PASSWORD
    }
```

server-middleware/post-subscriber.js

```
import axios from 'axios'

export default function (req, res, next) {
  req.on('data', (data) => {
    axios
      .post(
        process.env.API_URL + 'subscriber/',
        JSON.parse(data.toString()),
        {
          auth: {
            username: process.env.API_AUTH_USERNAME,
            password: process.env.API_AUTH_PASSWORD
          }
        },
```

Comment: `privateRuntimeConfig` is used only on the server as written in the documentation. Everything seems fine so far.

Comment: Also, `dev` is not exactly the best example in terms of checking the final result. Try to `yarn build` or `yarn generate` it locally to see the actual end result that you may have on production.

Comment: ok i will try. Thank you for your answer !